# Count how many cells are between the last value in the dataframe and the end of the row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using the pandas library in Python.

I have a data frame:

```
    0   1   2   3   4

0   0   0   0   1   0

1   0   0   0   0   1

2   0   0   1   0   0

3   1   0   0   0   0

4   0   0   1   0   0

5   0   1   0   0   0

6   1   0   0   1   1
```

Is it possible to create a new column that is a count of the number of cells that are empty between the end of the row and the last value above zero? Example data frame below:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   Value

0   0   0   0   1   0   1

1   0   0   0   0   1   0

2   0   0   1   0   0   2

3   1   0   0   0   0   4

4   0   0   1   0   0   2

5   0   1   0   0   0   3

6   1   0   0   1   1   0
```

Comment: What is expected output if only `0` row? It is number of all  columns, here `5` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. A 0 row is never an occurrence.

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `argmax`

```
df['value'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x.iloc[::-1] == 1).argmax(),1)

##OR
```

using `np.where`

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df.iloc[:,::-1] == 1,True,False).argmax(1)
```

---

```
   0  1  2  3  4  Value
0  0  0  0  1  0      1
1  0  0  0  0  1      0
2  0  0  1  0  0      2
3  1  0  0  0  0      4
4  0  0  1  0  0      2
5  0  1  0  0  0      3
6  1  0  0  1  1      0
```

Comment: OP didn't talked about that case...also eg has one in every row so i am thinking he expects 1 to be ther..@jezrael

Comment: i found them faster..another condition ?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['new'] = df.iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1).eq(0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  new
0  0  0  0  1  0    1
1  0  0  0  0  1    0
2  0  0  1  0  0    2
3  1  0  0  0  0    4
4  0  0  1  0  0    2
5  0  1  0  0  0    3
6  1  0  0  1  1    0
```

**Details**:

First change order of columns by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and slicing:

```
print (df.iloc[:, ::-1])
   4  3  2  1  0
0  0  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  1
4  0  0  1  0  0
5  0  0  0  1  0
6  1  1  0  0  1
```

Then use cumulative sum per rows by [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1))
   4  3  2  1  0
0  0  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1
2  0  0  1  1  1
3  0  0  0  0  1
4  0  0  1  1  1
5  0  0  0  1  1
6  1  2  2  2  3
```

Compare only `1` values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1).eq(0))
       4      3      2      1      0
0   True  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False
2   True   True  False  False  False
3   True   True   True   True  False
4   True   True  False  False  False
5   True   True   True  False  False
6  False  False  False  False  False
```

And last count them per rows by `sum`:

```
print (df.iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1).eq(0).sum(axis=1))
0    1
1    0
2    2
3    4
4    2
5    3
6    0
dtype: int64
```